# Создание нескольких клиентских сокетов

Tags: сокеты, клиент-сервер, qt, c++

Здравствуйте! Есть задание курсового проекта - написать шахматы с поддержкой игры по сети.
Язык программирования `C++`.
Пишу я в `Qt`.
Проблема в следующем: я не знаю как реализовать технически игру с несколькими противниками одновременно (аналогия - покеррум, игрок может играть сразу за несколькими столами).
Как поступить в данном случае:создавать отдельный клиентский сокет который будет принимать изменения для каждой отдельно взятой партии или реализовать это одним клиентским сокетом?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

`QTcpServer` слушает какой-нибудь порт и открывает `QTcpSocket` для каждого нового соединения, на нем же хранятся данные игр, например в `sqlite`. Можно даже для каждого `QTcpSocket`  или для обработки ряда игр отдельный `QThread` запускать, все зависит от нагрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Если компьютеров несколько, то думаю надо использовать несколько сокетов с одинаковым портом. Это думаю упростит логику приложения и уменьшит время на подключение/отключение/авторизацию между пк.